# Separate and convert native query from blade to eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Problem is I don't want to query inside blade cause it's a bad idea, I have 2 tables:

> "kriterias" table (id_kriteria, kriteria_name)
>   "evaluasis" table (id_food, id_kriteria, grade)

This is where my problems begin, I want this code to be applied in my blade view:

```
@for ($i=1;$i<=$jlhkriteria;$i++)
                    <?php $evaluasi = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT k.kriteria_name,e.id_kriteria,e.grade FROM evaluasis e, kriterias k WHERE
                e.id_food='$nis' AND e.id_kriteria='$i' AND e.id_kriteria=k.id_kriteria");
                    $hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($evaluasi, MYSQLI_ASSOC); ?>

<?php echo $hasil['kriteria_name']; ?>
<?php echo $hasil['grade']; ?>
<?php echo $i; ?>

@endfor
```

> As far as I know to join select query above using eloquent I use this
>   :

```
$evaluasi = Kriteria::with(array('evaluasi' => function($query) use ($nis) { 
        $query  ->where('id_food', $nis)
            ->where('id_kriteria',$i)//this $i value are get from for loop in blade
            ->select('id_kriteria', 'grade'); 
    }))->firstOrFail();
```

I always have problem when query something inside for loop in blade. My previous try are do the for loop in controller and foreach it in blade, for the $i value i get id_kriteria value, but I want to know how to query it in controller while taking $i value in blade and echo "kriteria_name" and "grade" and "$i" ?

**EDIT 1:**
add Model and controller
and have model for it:

```
Kriteria Model
    public function evaluasi()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Evaluasi::class, id_kriteria, id_kriteria);
    }

Evaluasi Model
    public function kriteria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kriteria::class, id_kriteria, id_kriteria);
    }
```

Controller part (don't wory about "nis" value, cause I get it from request it's integer) :

```
$jlhkriteria = Kriteria::count();
return view('rank', compact('nis', 'jlhkriteria));
```

Comment: What is the result of `dd($evaluasi)` of your Eloquent call?

Comment: i haven't check it, but i confirmed it using tinker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. First I need to fix the relationship, create many to many relationship using new food table and I will got pivot table.

```
//Kriteria Model
    public function food()
    {
        return $this->belongstoMany(Food::class, "pivot_table", id_kriteria, id_food);
    }

//Food Model
    public function kriteria()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Kriteria::class, "pivot_table", id_food, id_kriteria)->withPivot('grade');
    }
```

Controller :

```
$nis = 1;
$evaluasis = Food::find($nis);
$hasils = $evaluasis->kriteria;
```

Finally Show it in view :

```
@foreach($hasils as $hasil)
   <tr>
      <td>
          {{ $hasil->kriteria_name }}                            
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type=text name='grade{{ $hasil->id_kriteria }}' value='{{$hasil->pivot->grade }}'>          
      </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

> and done, it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your controller will be like this:

```
$kriteria = Kriteria::with('evaluasi')->get();
return view('rank', compact('kriteria'));
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach ($kriteria as $k)
    {{ $k->kriteria_name }}
    {{ $k->id }}

    @foreach ($k->evaluasi as $e)
        {{ $e->grade }}
        {{ $e->id }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Try this and check if it helps...

Comment: should i include $this-> before myqueryfunction? and how about my for loop in blade, should I put foreach loop inside the for loop?

Comment: If `myQueryFunction()` is inside the controller as a private function, for example, then yes.

Comment: And you can use only the foreach loop.

Comment: it's a public function, and where should I put my for loop? how do laravel know that I want to select evaluasis.id_kriteria = $i?

Comment: You don't need the for loop if you make the query in your controller or (preferably) model. The foreach will iterate over a previously loaded variable.

Comment: as you see in my eloquent  I put ->where('id_kriteria',$i) so how do I replace that?

Comment: I edited the code. Check if this helps you... And if its what you are looking for.

Comment: It's not working, it echo each of the kriteria 4 times.

Comment: So, add `nis` to compact and `{{ $nis }}` to view. If this does not solve the problem, sorry, but I can't help you. Probably I didn't understand what you really want.

Comment: I already put it, as I already explain it before in my question. What I want is    all kriteria and grade owned by id_food (based on $nis) are shown.

Comment: So, I didn't understand what you need, my friend. I'm sorry. Good luck!